# HTML / CSS - How to remove a gap between the header and a horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

Apparently, some people have had a problem, where there are gaps between `<li>` items in a horizontal menu.
In my case, however, there is a gap between a header and a horizontal menu.

[image]

The red zone is the header, and the black zone is the horizontal menu.

At first, I suspected that this problem came from the width properties of the header and the menu, but the values of both are the same (i.e. `width: 100%;`). When the width of the menu is `relative`, the menu becomes too short. I'm trying to do is to make the both lengths exactly the same.

Here are some parts of my coding. I'd appreciate if you would give any advice.

```css
#header {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#menu ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%; /*When this is relative or deleted, the menu becomes too short*/
  float: left;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
}
#menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  /*some coding*/
</div>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <!--some coding -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Set `#menu ul` to `padding:0`. Its the browser default *CSS* which are tricking you. Try considering any good *HTML* framework or use study about `reset.css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI now used to css Reset and for this you can

Define `#menu ul{padding:0;}`

```css
#header {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  margin-top: 0;
}
#menu ul{padding:0;}
#menu ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%; /*When this is relative or deleted, the menu becomes too short*/
  float: left;
  background-color: #0c0c0c;
}
#menu ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  /*some coding*/
</div>

<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <!--some coding -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**[What is css reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)**

Answer (score 1):

I looks like the body-tag comes with a browser-specific pre-defined margin/padding.

So, I suggest adding the following:

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

After adding this code, it worked all fine for me.

This is due to your header getting 100% of its parents width, which is the body. So, your header does in fact have a margin/padding of its parent, just specified through the bodys margin/padding.

Answer (score 1):

Remove predefined margins of body tag.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```